# Ne04j Index/Constraint like Schrodinger's cat - exists or not?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, constraints

My DB seems to be screwed. A constraint has failed, and the corresponding index is marked as "FAILED" (see below).

I thought dropping/re-creating the constraint or index would rebuild it, but no - when I try to create I'm told it already exists, and when I drop I'm told it doesn't.

Any ideas on how to (a) avoid getting into this situation and (b) how to get out of it?

Anyone at Neo want my DB to look at (it's not huge - maybe 50MB)?

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ schema
Indexes
  ON :Interest(uvid) FAILED (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Interest(uiid) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Offer(uoid)    ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Product(upid)  ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :User(uuid)     ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 

Constraints
  ON (user:User) ASSERT user.uuid IS UNIQUE
  ON (product:Product) ASSERT product.upid IS UNIQUE
  ON (interest:Interest) ASSERT interest.uiid IS UNIQUE
  ON (offer:Offer) ASSERT offer.uoid IS UNIQUE

neo4j-sh (?)$ create constraint on (i:Interest) assert i.uvid is unique;
CypherExecutionException: Already constrained CONSTRAINT ON ( interest:Interest ) ASSERT interest.uvid IS UNIQUE.
neo4j-sh (?)$ drop constraint on (i:Interest) assert i.uvid is unique;  
CypherExecutionException: Unable to drop CONSTRAINT ON ( interest:Interest ) ASSERT interest.uvid IS UNIQUE:
No such constraint CONSTRAINT ON ( interest:Interest ) ASSERT interest.uvid IS UNIQUE.

neo4j-sh (?)$ drop index on :Interest(uvid);
CypherExecutionException: Unable to drop index on :Interest(uvid): Index belongs to constraint: :Interest(uvid)
neo4j-sh (?)$ create index on :Interest(uvid);
CypherExecutionException: Already constrained CONSTRAINT ON ( interest:Interest ) ASSERT interest.uvid IS UNIQUE.
```

Answer (score 0):

This indeed sounds like a bug. Could you please file a issue for this at http://www.github.com/neo4j/neo4j ?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for reporting this. This is a bug which we hope to address soon. For now you cannot fix it using the public API.  Sorry for you trouble, this is definitely on our todo list.

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Posted as https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1492, together with a way to create a DB with the error.

Any timeline on subsequent milestones or release?